# How to resolve recurring conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch, git-pull, git-merge-conflict

I have two branches: `dev` and `feature`.

Branch feature was created from `dev`.

After that, there were new commits in the `dev` branch. I was merged `dev` branch into my feature. I have resolved many conflicts. However, I noticed that they were merged without merged commit.

Now I need to merge the `dev` into the `feature` branch again, because there are new commits in `dev`. But I'm running into the same conflicts that I already resolved with the previous merge.

Please, tell me how can I solve this problem. I spent a lot of time resolving conflicts and I don't want to do the same again.

Comment: Did you use rebase when merging?

Comment: There are different [types of merges](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge). You should take a look what kind of merge you want to do.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [git rerere](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere) (REuse REcorded REsolution)